# Proposed dark matter mass limits

Tags: dark-matter, beyond-the-standard-model

[A recent paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269321000083) ([arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.11575) also available) proposes to derive dark matter mass ranges of $10^{-3} \sim 10^{7} eV$ for a singlet scalar, parity-violating pseudoscalar, or spin-2 candidate, $10^{-21}\sim 10^{7}$ for an axion-like particle, $>10^{-22}$ for a gauged scalar field, $10^{-22} \sim 10^{7}$ for a vector gauge, and $10^2\sim 10^{10}$ for a dark fermion.

Combined with experimental search bounds, does this rule out any particle classes?  Does it rule out any currently viable supersymmetric models / grand-unified theories?

Comment: I was going to ask a question about the same paper myself, though a slightly different one: How generic are the assumptions that the authors make to derive these constraints, i.e. how "natural" are they or how "easy" is it to work around them?

Comment: I think what is happening is that under the assumptions that the authors make, only these mass ranges are allowed for these types of particles. Which means that if your favorite model is not based on these assumptions or gets around them, then these constraints do not apply. Explicitly the authors state this e.g. for gauged models.